# Missing /var/log/messages file in CentOS 6.8

Tags: linux, centos, syslog, rsyslog

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but my Linux box doesn't seem to be logging any info to the messages file. Will someone please help?

Here's the content of the /etc/rsyslog.conf file (rsyslog-5.8.10-10.el6_6.x86_64)

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file 

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
kern.*                                                  /var/log/kernel

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;dhclient.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

#local6.*                                                /var/log/drupal.log

# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

And here's the ps info:

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]# ps ax | grep syslog
11821 ?        Sl     0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
12336 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep syslog
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]#
```

Some sys info:

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 10 17:27:01 UTC 2016
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]#
```

And here's the content of my /var/log/ dir

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]# ls
total 4.6M
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  9 root  root  4.0K Jun  1 14:31 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x. 19 root  root  4.0K Mar 24  2014 ..
4.0K drwxr-x---.  2 root  root  4.0K May 11 02:17 audit
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  2 root  root  1.5K Jun  1 00:11 boot.log
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  utmp     0 Jun  1 03:44 btmp
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  utmp     0 May 26 21:12 btmp-20160601
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root  4.0K Jun  1 03:44 ConsoleKit
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 cron
1.8M -rw-------.  1 root  root  1.8M Jun  1 14:01 cron-20160601
 28K -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root   25K Jun  1 00:11 dmesg
 24K -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root   23K May 23 01:32 dmesg.old
   0 -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     0 May 27 03:44 dracut.log
2.4M -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root  2.4M May 27 03:44 dracut.log-20160527
4.0K drwxr-x---.  2 exim  exim  4.0K Jun  1 14:31 exim
4.0K drwx------.  2 root  root  4.0K Jun  1 14:31 httpd
   0 -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 kernel
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root   250 Jun  1 14:25 kernel-20160601
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root   64K Jun  1 14:18 lastlog
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 maillog
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 May 31 23:29 maillog-20160601
   0 -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 messages
   0 -rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:23 messages-20160601
4.0K drwx------.  2 munge munge 4.0K Feb 20  2014 munge
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root  4.0K Jun  1 03:44 newrelic
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  2 ntp   ntp   4.0K May 11 16:04 ntpstats
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 secure
 68K -rw-------.  1 root  root   61K Jun  1 14:18 secure-20160601
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 spooler
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 May 31 23:29 spooler-20160601
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 May 26 21:11 tallylog
   0 -rw-rw-r--.  1 root  utmp     0 Jun  1 14:31 wtmp
164K -rw-rw-r--.  1 root  utmp  160K Jun  1 14:18 wtmp-20160601
   0 -rw-------.  1 root  root     0 Jun  1 14:31 yum.log
 24K -rw-------.  1 root  root   18K May 26 21:13 yum.log-20160601
[root@ip-172-31-29-157 log]#
```

P.S.: FWIW, kernel isn't logging anything either. And yes, rsyslog is running.

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` that might be negating the config in the main config file?

Comment: @Andrew that directory is completely empty :(

Comment: Please run rsyslog in config-checking mode: **/sbin/rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N1**. And show output.